# How to compute the regression coefficient in R with exp and ln?

Tags: r, regression

I would like to compute the regression coefficients `a` and `b`  for my data using this equation:

```
y=exp(a * 1 - t  + b * 1 - t )
```

and this data(example):

```
         t = c(1,2,5,4,8,7,5,1,2,5,4,1,2,1,5)
         t1 = c(1,2,4,4,5,3,7,5,6,8,7,1,2,1,5)
```

I know we can use

```
           lm(y ~ t + t2)
```

but I do not know how to include  `exp` and `ln`. PLease help

Comment: Just take a log on both sides so that it will be become `lny=aln(1-t/h)+bln(1-t/t1)` and you can then run log linear regression, if that is what you are looking . You can also use non-linear regression if you don't want to transform to log linear.

Comment: This is not a programming question really... it has more to do with mathematical reasoning. Create temp variables and calculate the regression on them instead of your original variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform this regression:

```
y = exp(a * ln(1 - t / h) + b * ln(1 - t / t1))
```

first apply `log` on both sides:

```
log(y) = a * ln(1 - t / h) + b * ln(1 - t / t1)
```

If it helps, use auxiliary variables:

```
z  <- log(y)
w1 <- log(1 - t / h)
w2 <- log(1 - t / t1)
regr <- lm(z ~ w1 + w2)
```

Comment: `In log(1 - t/h) : NaNs produced` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question it looks like `t`, `t1`, and `h` are all independent variables, `y` is the dependent variable, and `a` and `b` are the parameters of the model. Using the definitions `x1 = t/h` and `x2=t/t1`, your model formula is equivalent to:

```
y = (1-x1)^a * (1-x2)^b
```

which is clearly non-linear in the parameters a and b. In this type of situation you are generally much better off using non-linear least squares, `nls(...)`. Why?

Least squares regression is based on several assumptions, the most important of which is that *the error in y is normally distributed with mean 0 and constant variance*. If that is true for `y` then it most certainly will not be true for `log(y)`. So running a regression using `log(y)` as the independent variable will give you numbers for `a` and `b`, but statistics of the fit (e.g., error estimates in `a` and `b`, etc.) will be meaningless.

Finally, your dataset is ill-conditioned in the sense that for several of your cases either `x1 = 1` or `x2 = 1` or both. In that case `log(1-x1) = -Inf` or `log(1-x2) = -Inf`. Also, there are several cases where `x1 > 1` or `x2 > 1`. In those cases `log(...)` is undefined.